# Showing the error "A previous catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or a super type `System.Exception' " in my C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Showing the error "A previous catch clause already catch clause already catches all exceptions of this or a super type `System.Exception' " in my C# code

```
using System;   
class Test { 
    static void Main()  { 
        try{ 
            int a=10,b=0,c=0;c=a/b ; 
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }   
        catch(System.Exception e) { 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        } 
        catch(System.DivideByZeroException ex) {  
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The problem is the order, just put the `DivideByZeroException` first.  The order should always be more specific to less specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception handlers are processed in order from top to bottom and only the first matching exception handler is invoked. Because your first handler catches `System.Exception`, and all exceptions derive from `System.Exception`, it'll catch everything, and the second handler will never execute.

The best practice for multiple exception handlers is to order them from specific to general, like this:

```
using System;   
class Test { 
    static void Main()  { 
        try{ 
            int a=10,b=0,c=0;c=a/b ; 
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }   
        catch(System.DivideByZeroException ex) {  
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        } 
        catch(System.Exception e) { 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

If you absolutely positively have to handle `System.Exception` first (although I can't think of a reason why) you could write an exception filter to allow DivideByZero through, like this:

```
using System;   
class Test { 
    static void Main()  { 
        try{ 
            int a=10,b=0,c=0;c=a/b ; 
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }   
        catch(System.Exception e) 
        when (!(e is DivideByZeroException)){ 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        } 
        catch(System.DivideByZeroException ex) {  
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Note: Per MSDN, [you should avoid catching general exception types like `System.Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx).